# .NET LocalReport / .rdlc AppDomain issues

Tags: c#, .net, rdlc, appdomain, localreport

I'm using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport and .rdlc Report files to generate .pdf:s. This is done in the background in a Windows Service (.NET 4.6, x64, VS2015).

I'm having two issues:

1. The Windows service keeps consuming memory an eventually OutOfMemoryException is thrown and process terminates
2. At one occation the entire WindowsSerivce terminated with UnhandledException despite everything being enclosed in a try-catch statement.

Now, I've read somewhere LocalReport under .NET 4 has changed to live in it's own AppDomain.

So, when using LocalReport:

- Are you supposed to always call localReport.ReleaseSandboxAppDomain() after each and every localReport.Render()?
- Do I have to do something to handle any exceptions that may occur in the LocalReport sandbox AppDomain?